# How to get the selected value of a jcombobox to a variable?

Tags: java, swing, data-binding, netbeans, jcombobox

I have a jcombobox with bonded values.I need to get the selected value to a variable.
Here is my code.

```
String item = cmbItems.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

But when I print the value of item variable it gives as follows.

```
auction.items[itemNo=1]
```

(My data table items has two columns itemNo and itemName.)
But the jcombobox displays the item names.
I need to get that item name to a variable.

How can I do this?

Please help....Thank you in advance.

Here's how I defined cmbItems

```
cmbItems = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

cmbItems.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
            JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            if (value instanceof Items) {
                Items i = (Items)value;
                setText(i.getItem());
            }
            return this;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you show us how you are defining cmbItems?

Comment: it still gives the same result..I cannot add comments to @Ben S answer.It is frozen. So I posted here.

Comment: @patterned: Do u know what's the error?

Comment: Can you show some more code?  I've never overridden a renderer like you are doing.  Can I see how you are adding items to the `cmbItems` combobox?